# Python: Converting HEX string to bytes

Tags: python, string, udp, hex, arrays

I'm trying to make byte frame which I will send via UDP. I have class **Frame** which has attributes **sync**, **frameSize**, **data**, **checksum** etc. I'm using hex strings for value representation. Like this:

```
testFrame = Frame("AA01","0034","44853600","D43F")
```

Now, I need to concatenate this hex values together and convert them to byte array like this?!

```
def convertToBits(self):
    stringMessage = self.sync + self.frameSize + self.data + self.chk
    return b16decode(self.stringMessage)
```

But when I print converted value I don't get the same values or I don't know to read python notation correctly:

```
This is sync: AA01
This is frame size: 0034
This is data:44853600
This is checksum: D43F

b'\xaa\x01\x004D\x856\x00\xd4?'
```

So, first word is converted ok (AA01 -> \xaa\x01) but (0034 -> \x004D) it's not the same. I tried to use **bytearray.fromhex** because I can use spaces between bytes but I got same result. Can you help me to send same hex words via UDP?

Comment: The string 4D is \x34\x44 so there is no problem, you just misread the output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python displays any byte that can represent a *printable ASCII character* as that character. `4` is the same as `\x34`, but as it opted to print the ASCII character in the representation.

So `\x004` is really the same as `\x00\x34`, `D\x856\x00` is the same as `\x44\x85\x36\x00`, and `\xd4?` is the same as `\xd4\x3f`, because:

```
>>> b'\x34'
'4'
>>> b'\x44'
'D'
>>> b'\x36'
'6'
>>> b'\x3f'
'?'
```

This is just the *representation* of the bytes value; the value is *entirely correct* and you don't need to do anything else.

If it helps, you can visualise the `bytes` values as hex again using [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'\xaa\x01\x004D\x856\x00\xd4?')
b'aa01003444853600d43f'
```

and you'll see that `4`, `D`, `6` and `?` are once again represented by the correct hexadecimal characters.